# How can I set state of res from axios in reactNative

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, axios

I want to read an array of data from API, and I use axios in my react native code, but the state at first return null array and then return all index. so how can I set state of the response ??

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
this.state = {
  categories: []
}
}
loadData = () => {
  axios.get("http://my-fashion.co.il/samerjammal_APIs/api/categories")
  .then((res) => {
    console.log('data from api', res.data.data[0].imageURL)
    this.setState({
      categories:res.data.data
    })
  })
}

componentDidMount(){
this.loadData();
}
```

and this the component :

```js
  <Image
                source={this.state.categories[0].imageURL}
                style={{
                  resizeMode: "cover",
                  maxHeight: deviceHeight / 2,
                  flex: 1,
                  width: null,
                  height : 305
                }}
              />
```

any help, please ?? 
and i try use self, and didn't work also :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to render again once data is fetched.
Also it is a good idea to add a loading indicator and a way to catch fetching error.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
this.state = {
  categories: [], 
  loading: true,
}
}
loadData = () => {
  axios.get("http://my-fashion.co.il/samerjammal_APIs/api/categories")
  .then((res) => {
    console.log('data from api', res.data.data[0].imageURL)
    this.setState({
      categories:res.data.data,
      loading: false,
    })
  })
}

componentDidMount(){
this.loadData();
}

render() {
  const { categories, loading } = this.state;

return (
  <View  style={{
                  maxHeight: deviceHeight / 2,
                  flex: 1,
                  width: null,
                  height : 305
                }} >
  { loading ? <ActivityIndicator style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill} size=“large” /> : (
  <Image
     source={categories[0].imageURL}
                style={{
                  resizeMode: "cover",
                  ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
                }}
              />
    )
  }
</View> )}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could only show an image if a URL exists:

```
{ this.state.categories[0].imageURL &&
  <Image source={this.state.categories[0].imageURL}/>
}
```

or you could check at the top of your `render()` method whether you have a URL and put in a placeholder source instead:

```
const source = this.state.categories[0].imageURL || require('assets/placeholder.png');
return <Image source={source} />;
```

Comment: Actually I try it and also not work , give me 'getHostNode' error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'imageURL' of undefined
 :(

Comment: and about second method , what you mean about : || require('assets/placeholder.png')

Comment: @developer If you don't set up your state in the constructor then you will need to check whether `categories` exists and whether it has any items. About the second method i mean you could include a placeholder image to display if imageURL doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   categories: []
  }
}
loadData = () => {
  let that = this;
      axios.get("http://my-fashion.co.il/samerjammal_APIs/api/categories")
       .then((res) => {
       console.log('data from api', res.data.data[0].imageURL)
       that.setState({
       categories:res.data.data
      })
    })
}

componentDidMount(){
  this.loadData();
}



    and image component should be

  <Image
            source={this.state.categories[0].imageURL || require('assets/placeholder.png')}
            style={{
              resizeMode: "cover",
              maxHeight: deviceHeight / 2,
              flex: 1,
              width: null,
              height : 305
            }}
          />
```

Comment: and actually I try this '  let that = this;' 
but it's not work :( 
what you mean about 'equire('assets/placeholder.png')'
this 'assets/placeholder.png' for what link ? 
from my api ??

Comment: some dummy image from your local system or from anywhere

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct form of @aaron-brager solution:

```
{ (this.state.categories.length > 0) &&
  <Image source={this.state.categories[0].imageURL}/>
}
```

or

```
const source = this.state.categories.length ? this.state.categories[0].imageURL : require('assets/placeholder.png');
return <Image source={source} />;
```